# JLabel setText not updating text

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I am trying to update a JLabel by using the `setText()` method, but I can't redraw JLabel. Do I have to use the `repaint()` method to do that?

Here is the part of code, I do not get any errors, but it is not updating the JLabel.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    fc = new JFileChooser();
    if(e.getSource() == addButton) {
         int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(Main.this);
         if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                filesList = fc.getSelectedFiles();
                setFilesList(filesList);

                StringBuilder logString = new StringBuilder();
                logString.append("Files to Convert " + "\n");
                for(int i = 0; i < getFiles().length; i++) {
                    logString.append(filesList[i].getAbsolutePath());
                }
                //JLabel log = new JLabel(); created above.
                log.setText(logString.toString());
            } else {
                //log.append("Open command cancelled by user." + newline);
        }
        //log.setCaretPosition(log.getDocument().getLength());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd begin by saying a jLabel cannot display the newline character. Wrap it in <html> and use <br/> tags.

Comment: Are you sure you're not re-initializing the `log` variable to a new `JLabel` instance *after* you added it to your layout manager?

Comment: yes, actually i intialized it with the constructor.

Comment: JLabel requires no repaint call. Simply calling `setText(...)` will change the label's text, and that is all that is required.

Answer (score 14):

JLabel requires no repaint call. Simply calling setText(...) will change the label's text, and that is all that is required.

I wonder if your problem is a concurrency issue, that you are doing a long-running process on the Swing event thread and that this is preventing your label from updating its text.

If so, then consider doing your long-running process in a background thread such as that provided by a SwingWorker, and then updating your JLabel's text on the Swing thread, such as can be done via the SwingWorker's publish/process methods.

For more on this, please have a look at the [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) tutorial.

Also Mario De... is correct about not being able to print simple new-lines on a JLabel. 1+ to his answer.

Answer (score 5):

I'm a bit stumped on how the repainting of frames/component works in Java. You can `Paint(Graphics g)`, `update(Graphics g)` which according to the javadoc just calls `paint(g)`. Finally there's also `repaint()`...

If none of those seem to work, wouldn't it just be easier to create the label only at the line where you are currently trying to set the text?

Edit: there is also the option of using an ineditable textArea. Not only can it display the standard newline character, but you can put it in a jScrollPane, which is handy when you have lots of files in the log, and you don't need to repaint text components to display updated text. The bonus is magnificent imo...

Comment: You're right on the mark about JLabel not allowing simple new-lines, and using JTextArea instead. 1+.

Answer (score 4):

This simple example works for me so problem is not `JLabel` but some bug in other part of your source code. Please post full source code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("JLabel test");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    Panel p = new Panel();
    p.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    Button button = new Button("Change");
    final JLabel label = new JLabel(Long.toString(Long.MAX_VALUE));

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText(Long.toString(e.getWhen()));
        }
    });

    p.add(button);
    p.add(label);
    frame.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.pack();

}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I have run into a similar problem. I tried to `setText("Good Bye")` in `actionPerformed()` in an exit button ActionListener before disposing my JFrame right there, but the text was not changing.

Eventually I realized that my label was not getting updated as I was disposing the frame in the anonymous ActionListener class. After I had let the code leave `ActionListener.actionPerformed()`, the label text got updated.

I had to dispose my JFrame in a new thread though to ensure that:

1. `actionPerformed` is finished so that the main thread returns from the anonymous nested class and updates the label in the main class.
2. A new thread is started which waits for a second to allow "Good Bye" to be read.
3. This new thread the disposes the frame.

Answer (score 3):

`repaint()` won't work here.

Simply use `label_name.paintImmediately(label_name.getVisibleRect());`

It will get updated right away.

Answer (score 0):

Please try -

```
jlabel.setText("Your Text");
jLabel.setVisisble(true);
```