# Why isn't the text in the JLabel in my application updated accordingly when I press the button?

Tags: java

The field lblNewLabel_1 is changed to "Server Init Attempted (Check Console for Status)!" in the button's ActionListener; why does it not change when I press the button?

Could this be caused by the startServer method calling a while(true) loop?

```
package server;

import java.awt.Font;

public class StudyItServerGUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    public JLabel lblNewLabel_1;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                try {
                    StudyItServerGUI window = new StudyItServerGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public StudyItServerGUI() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 378, 251);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("StudyIt Server Creation Application!");
        lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("MT Extra", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        lblNewLabel.setBounds(0, 0, 372, 16);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(241, 68, 121, 93);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

        JList list = new JList();
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(list);

        JButton btnStart = new JButton("START!");
        btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ServerApplication.startServer();
                        lblNewLabel_1.setText("Server Init Attempted (Check Console for Status)!");

                        //y u no change
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
        btnStart.setBounds(241, 159, 117, 29);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnStart);

        JButton btnCreateQuestionset = new JButton("Create QuestionSet");
        btnCreateQuestionset.setBounds(32, 68, 146, 98);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnCreateQuestionset);

        lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel();
        lblNewLabel_1.setText("yes");
        lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Charcoal CY", Font.BOLD, 16));
        lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(6, 197, 366, 26);
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1);
    }
    static class ServerApplication{

            private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
            private static Socket clientSocket;
            private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
            private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
            private static String message;
            private static PrintWriter printWriter;

            static void startServer() {
                try {
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);  //Server socket
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Could not listen on port: 4444");
                }

                System.out.println("Server started. Listening to the port 4444");

                while (true) {
                    try {
                        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();   //accept the client connection
                        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
                        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); //get the client message
                        message = bufferedReader.readLine();

                        System.out.println(message);
                        //StudyIt

                        inputStreamReader.close();
                        clientSocket.close();

                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                        System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the output that you posted the desired output? Or is that the output that you receive? Please post whichever of the two is not posted and specify which one is which. thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [JLabel setText is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10132859/jlabel-settext-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the while(true) loop checking for any new messages into a thread, as opposed to the action within the button which initiates the server. This will stop the frame from being updated to to unreachable code.

Answer (score -1):

What is garbled about it? Is it by chance all being printed as separate lines and you want to print on the same line? That would be because you use `System.out.println` and not `System.out.print`.